# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "register" (type string) at path "_id" for model "User"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am completely Stuck tried everything possible but no luck to resolve this error

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "register" at path "_id" for model "User"

i am using mongodb 4.2 and "mongoose": "^5.12.10"

Please anyone help me.

users_router.js

```
const { User } = require('../models/user_schema');
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

router.get('/:id', async(req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params.id);
    const user = await User.findById(req.params.id).select('-passwordHash');

    if (!user) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'The user with the given ID was not found.' })
    }
    res.status(200).send(user);

})

router.post('/register', async(req, res) => {
    let user = new User({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        passwordHash: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 10)
    })

    console.log(user, "harman");

    user = await user.save();

    if (!user)
        return res.status(400).send('the user cannot be created!')

    res.send(user);
})
```

// This is Schema

user_schema.js

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    
    const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        passwordHash: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        }
    
    });
    
    userSchema.virtual('id').get(function() {
        return this._id.toHexString();
    });
    
    userSchema.set('toJSON', {
        virtuals: true,
    });
    
    exports.User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
    exports.userSchema = userSchema;
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove `_id` field while creating a new `user`? I don't think you have to provide an `_id` like that. It's auto increment

Comment: @MuratColyaran Yes i tried to remove it , but still getting same error , Thank you for quick reply.

Comment: I couldn't find anything wrong with your code. Have you tried to remove `virtual id` part in your schema just for testing? And what's `register` in the error message?

Comment: @MuratColyaran : yes i did that still getting error : 
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "register" (type string) at path "_id" for model "User"
    at model.Query.exec (E:\development\jqub\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4470:21)
    at model.Query.Query.then

Comment: @MuratColyaran : i am sorry , it's resolved now  , it was error due to i was send wrong request type , was sending GET instead of POST in POSTMAN ...